# Why does Germany look equally as large as Afghanistan on Google Maps?

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps, latitude-longitude, area, dimensions

I snipped Germany and Afghanistan from the same Google Maps view:

[image: Germnany_and_Afganistan]

They look like they are about the same size. Here is the full screenshot:

[image: Google_Maps_screenshot]

**The problem:** Afghanistan has an area of [image: Afghanistan_Area] while Germany has an area of [image: Germany_Area] (according to Wikipedia).

Now, I know that Germany appears larger because higher latitudes are stretched more when drawn on 2D. But I calculated the difference between the perimeter on latitude 34° (Afghanistan) and latitude 50° (Germany).

Given that the Earth's radius at the equator is 1, the relationship between latitude and the radius on that latitude should follow the circle function

- [image: formula_1]
- [image: formula_2] gives us `y = 0.926`
- [image: formula_3] gives us `y = 0.831`

So the radius is `0.926` in Afghanistan and `0.831` in Germany.

**This is only a difference of 11% caused by the higher latitude. According to Wikipedia, however, Afghanistan is 83% larger than Germany.**

So where does the rest of Germany's scaling on Google Maps come from?

Please excuse my incorrect naming of geographic terms, I have absolutely no experience in geography.

Comment: You need to research *projections*, more specifically, the areal distortion of the Web Mercator projection.

Comment: also areas go as the **square** of the error not linearly

Comment: https://xkcd.com/2082/

Answer (score 1):

***Before August 2018***

Germany looks equally as large as Afghanistan on Google Maps because of the Web Mercator projection that was applied.

> Web Mercator is a slight variant of the Mercator projection, one used
>   primarily in Web-based mapping programs.

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) about the Mercator projection that

> The Mercator projection is a cylindrical map projection. It became the
>   standard map projection for nautical navigation because of its ability
>   to represent lines of constant course, known as rhumb lines or
>   loxodromes, as straight segments that conserve the angles with the
>   meridians. Although the linear scale is equal in all directions around
>   any point, thus preserving the angles and the shapes of small objects
>   (making it a conformal map projection), **the Mercator projection
>   distorts the size of objects** as the latitude increases from the
>   Equator to the poles, where the scale becomes infinite.
>
> The Mercator projection exaggerates areas far from the equator.

If we consider the geo-centroid coordinates (data were taken from [Country centroids](https://worldmap.harvard.edu/data/geonode:country_centroids_az8)) for both countries

```
Country         Latitude         Longitude
Germany         51.1069818075    10.385780508
Afganistan      33.8352307278    66.0047336558
```

it is easy to see that the Latitude value of Germany is greater than Afganistan which means that Germany located closer to the North pole where the distortion is bigger.

---

***After August 2018***

I think with a new edition of Google Maps, the issue about area distortion is not a big concern anymore.

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps) that

> Google Maps used a variant of the Mercator projection ([Web Mercator
>   projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator_projection)),
>   and therefore cannot accurately show areas around the poles. However,
>   in August 2018, the desktop version of Google Maps was updated to show
>   a 3D globe.

Have a look at the "nearly" the same view of Google Maps.

[image: Google_Maps_view]

I suppose it quite obvious now that there is an areal difference between Germany and Afganistan.

**References:**

- [Google Maps now depicts the Earth as a globe](https://www.theverge.com/2018/8/5/17653122/google-maps-update-mercator-projection-earth-isnt-flat)
- [Google Maps now zooms out to a globe instead of a flat Earth](https://www.engadget.com/2018/08/03/google-maps-globe-mode/)
- [Zooming out on Google Maps no longer shows a flat map](https://mashable.com/article/google-maps-3d-globe-/?europe=true#WPdq3JXatOqH)
- [Google Maps is now a globe — just zoom out](https://venturebeat.com/2018/08/02/google-maps-is-now-a-globe-just-zoom-out/)